# How to figure out jenkins pipeline command from plugin source?

Tags: plugins, jenkins

The unity3d jenkins plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/unity3d-plugin/#documentation is quite old. It hasn't been updated since 2015! I'd like to use it in a pipeline script, but the documentation doesn't say what the pipeline syntax is.

I'm not a jenkins plugin author pro, but there's a @DataBoundConstructor here https://github.com/jenkinsci/unity3d-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/unity3d/Unity3dBuilder.java#L53 that looks promising, but the following doesn't work:

`Unity3DBuilder: unity3dName: "Unity 2019.4.5", argLine: "-quit -batchmode -projectPath . -logFile ${WORKSPACE}\compilelog.txt"`

The error says `unexpected token: unity3dName`.

EDIT: I tried this alternative syntax and also got an error:

`Unity3dBuilder(unity3dName: "Unity 2019.4.5", argLine: "-quit -batchmode -projectPath . -logFile ${WORKSPACE}\\compilelog.txt")`

With the error: `No such DSL method 'Unity3dBuilder'`

Am I right in assuming that any old plugin can be used from a pipeline script? And if so, what would be the correct syntax for this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins are not inherently [pipeline compatible](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md).

Light reading:
[Refactoring a Jenkins plugin for compatibility with Pipeline jobs](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/25/update-plugin-for-pipeline/)

[Writing Pipeline-Compatible Plugins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/pipeline-integration/)